# python flask sqlalchemy running sequential queries resulting in errors

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working with Python/Flask and sqlAlchemy I am running this code that works fine,

```
sel1 = select([staff.c.start_date,
            func.sum(leave.c.hours).label('hours_taken')
            ]) \
    .select_from(join(staff, leave, (staff.c.name == leave.c.name))) \
    .where(leave.c.leave_start >= '2016-01-01') \
    .where(leave.c.leave_end <= '2016-03-30') \
    .where(leave.c.hr_status == 'RP_Approved') \
    .where(leave.c.name == 'User 1') \
    .group_by(staff.c.name, staff.c.start_date)

jan_user = FlaskApp.db_connect().execute(sel1).fetchone()
jan_user = dict(jan_user)
if(jan_user):
    staff_member['JanMarTaken'] = jan_user.hours_taken
    staff_member['start_date'] = jan_user.start_date
else:
    staff_member['JanMarTaken'] = 0
```

I get an object returned the data that I would expect.

However when I run the following code,

```
sel2 = select([staff.c.start_date,
            func.sum(leave.c.hours).label('hours_taken')
            ]) \
    .select_from(join(staff, leave, (staff.c.name == leave.c.name))) \
    .where(leave.c.leave_start >= '2016-04-01') \
    .where(leave.c.leave_end <= '2016-09-30') \
    .where(leave.c.hr_status == 'RP_Approved') \
    .where(leave.c.name == 'User 1') \
    .group_by(staff.c.name, staff.c.start_date)

mar_user = FlaskApp.db_connect().execute(sel2).fetchone()
if(mar_user):
    mar_user = dict(mar_user)
    return mar_user
    staff_member['MarSeptHours'] = mar_user.hours_taken
    staff_member['start_date'] = mar_user.start_date
else:
    staff_member['MarSeptHours'] = 0
```

and I get the following error,

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'hours_taken'

I don't understand why the first query would work fine, but the second fails, there are exactly the same query, just with a different date range. Is there a way to solve this? Or better yet incorporate into one query?

===== Changed code example ====

```
sel = select([staff.c.name,
                  staff.c.leave_allowance,
                  func.sum(leave.c.hours).label('hours_used'),
                  (staff.c.leave_allowance - func.sum(leave.c.hours)).label('remaining_hours')
                  ]) \
        .select_from(join(leave, staff, (staff.c.name == leave.c.name))) \
        .where(staff.c.name == 'Beth Field') \
        .where(leave.c.hr_status == "RP_Approved") \
        .where(extract('year', leave.c.leave_start) == '2016') \
        .group_by(staff.c.name, staff.c.leave_allowance)

staff_member = FlaskApp.db_connect().execute(sel).fetchone()
staff_member = dict(staff_member)

sel1 = select([staff.c.start_date,
            func.sum(leave.c.hours).label('hours_taken')
            ]) \
    .select_from(join(staff, leave, (staff.c.name == leave.c.name))) \
    .where(leave.c.leave_start >= '2016-01-01') \
    .where(leave.c.leave_end <= '2016-03-30') \
    .where(leave.c.hr_status == 'RP_Approved') \
    .where(leave.c.name == 'User 1') \
    .group_by(staff.c.name, staff.c.start_date)

jan_user = FlaskApp.db_connect().execute(sel1).fetchone()
jan_user = dict(jan_user)
if(jan_user):
    staff_member['JanMarTaken'] = jan_user.hours_taken
    staff_member['start_date'] = jan_user.start_date
else:
    staff_member['JanMarTaken'] = 0

sel2 = select([staff.c.start_date,
            func.sum(leave.c.hours).label('hours_taken')
            ]) \
    .select_from(join(staff, leave, (staff.c.name == leave.c.name))) \
    .where(leave.c.leave_start >= '2016-04-01') \
    .where(leave.c.leave_end <= '2016-09-30') \
    .where(leave.c.hr_status == 'RP_Approved') \
    .where(leave.c.name == 'User 1') \
    .group_by(staff.c.name, staff.c.start_date)

mar_user = FlaskApp.db_connect().execute(sel2).fetchone()
if(mar_user):
    mar_user = dict(mar_user)
    staff_member['MarSeptHours'] = mar_user.hours_taken
    staff_member['start_date'] = mar_user.start_date
else:
    staff_member['MarSeptHours'] = 0
```

In this code I have removed the return (which was for debugging) and now I am getting,

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: No they arent the same, why do you have a `return` statement in the second code, and i think it's the first code that fails, because anything below the return statement in the second code will never be executed

Comment: @danidee: It think the return statement was just for debugging.

Comment: @MrLeeh Then the OP should have commented it out or removed it totally, as the question is currently, there's no way to know the intention of the return statement unless the OP tells us.

Comment: But it's a bit strange. You create a dict from your query object and access the keys via properties. Shouldn't it be `mar_user['hours_taken']` instead?

Comment: Yeah, that's why i think it's the first query that actually fails and the second one never gets to the point where it was eventually going to fail too (because of the return statement)

Comment: I have added some edited code.

Comment: Fixed it! The query was not returning any data so could not be turned into a dictionary.  Now is there a way to merge all this into one query?